# How do I write an rspec test for a controller method that only renders html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

My application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def hello
    render html: "Hello, world!"
  end
end
```

I have tried this spec but it does not work:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationController do
  render_views

  describe '#hello' do
    it 'renders hello world' do
      get :hello_world

      expect(response.body).to include("Hello, world!")
    end
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) ApplicationController#hello renders hello world
     Failure/Error: get :hello_world

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"hello_world", :controller=>"application"}
```

How do I write an Rspec test to test that this method renders this html?

Comment: show your work, what did you try, what is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that it can't find the route `hello_world`, try changing

```
it 'renders hello world' do
  get :hello_world

  expect(response.body).to include('hello world')
end
```

to

```
it 'renders hello world' do
  get :hello

  expect(response.body).to include('hello world')
end
```

and see if it helps

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you for guiding me both how best to post here and for also making my test work!

Comment: glad to be of help, would you accept the answer if it helped you?